# Сложносочиненные предложения. Запятая перед соединительным союзом

Tags: пунктуация

**– Все будет хорошо, –  наклонился ко мне бородач() и с губ его сорвались эти слова.**

**Затем гол забили мюнхенцы: атакующий смог удачно принять мяч() и тот, задержавшись в ногах у игрока лишь на пару секунд, влетел в сетку.**

В этих примерах следует руководствоваться данным правилом?
"Запятая перед одиночными соединительными и разделительными союзами – и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо – не ставится, если простые предложения сложносочиненного предложения вместе поясняют общее для них третье предложение, предшествующее им и связанное с ними бессоюзной связью".

Или все-таки запятая между простыми предложениями тут нужна? Сбивает то, что одно предложение – с прямой речью, а второе для моего глаза сильно "распадается" из-за двоеточия на отдельные части, и возникает желание поставить запятую перед "и". Буду благодарен, если поможете избавиться от сомнений и объясните, в чем я не прав.

Comment: Прямую речь (или реплику) разбирают отдельно от авторских слов, как два разных предложения. Поэтому реплика бородача не есть общий элемент. // Во втором случае запятая также нужна, но я не могу доказать это с позиции грамматики, поэтому пишу не ответ, а комментарий, и надеюсь, что кто-нибудь ответит подробно — сам с интересом почитаю.

Comment: Не нравится мне первый пример. Сначала должно быть сказано о словах, а потом уже о наклоне. После прямой речи должны сразу же идти вводящие её слова.

Comment: @oleedd  А если так: – Все будет хорошо, – наклонился ко мне бородач, когда (в то время как) с губ его сорвались эти слова.

Comment: @Sharon Тоже нет. Тогда надо прямую речь в конец ставить. Да и так не очень правильно, потому что люди наклоняются, чтобы потом сказать, а не делают это одновременно.

Comment: Вас в редакторы пускать нельзя, все авторы от вас разбегутся. Здесь, может, важна именно первая художественная деталь, а у вас только одно – должно, должны.  Ну просто одни долги, а не художественная речь. Тогда придумайте свой вариант.

Comment: Говорю, как надо, чтобы было правильно. А не хотите правильно — ваше дело, всё равно мысль поймут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Затем гол забили мюнхенцы: атакующий смог удачно принять мяч, и тот (=он), задержавшись в ногах у игрока лишь на пару секунд, влетел в сетку.***

Два предложения после двоеточия выполняют разную функцию: первое указывает на причину, во втором просматривается значение следствия, хотя графически связь между этими двумя предложениями выражена сочинительным союзом. Местоимение ТОТ легко замещается личным местоимением ОН без ущерба для смысла, это ещё одна (формальная) причина постановки запятой перед И.

Предложения после двоеточия неоднородны, поэтому запятая перед И нужна.

Ср.: ***Затем гол забили мюнхенцы: [потому что]атакующий смог удачно принять мяч, и [так что] тот (=он), задержавшись в ногах у игрока лишь на пару секунд, влетел в сетку.***

Comment: Вооот! И я так подумал и предположил в комментах, что в этом предложении будет действовать правило Розенталя. Несмотря на то, что "тот" не личное местоимение, оно здесь де-факто идентично личному.

Comment: У Розенталя правило про местоимения не связано с общим элементом (там вообще речь о простых предложениях, нескольких грамматических основах), оно не указывает на необходимость запятой даже при общем элементе. Просто чтобы все понимали, что на него ссылаться не корректно.

Comment: "Так что" не подходит, потому что удачное принятие мяча совсем не означает, что мяч попадёт в сетку. И здесь больше похоже на раскрытие содержания (как именно забили), чем на причину: *Почему забили гол? Потому что атакующий удачно принял мяч.* Нет, это не логично (для тех, кто хоть раз смотрел футбол).

Comment: Тут похожий случай? **Я подумал: вероятно, приступ с Лешей случается не в первый раз, и, наверное, он хорошо знает, как ведет себя в таком состоянии.**

Comment: В СПП по такому же принципу действовать?

Comment: И еще один пример, последний. Здесь СПП с однородными? Или как его обозвать? Как здесь быть с запятой перед "и"? **Он подошел к окну и увидел, что возле магазина стоят две машины() и что возле них суетливо двигаются люди в черных одеждах: подходят к дверям магазина и возвращаются к багажникам автомобилей, − видимо, что-то грузят.**

Comment: @Александр Когда два "что", точно однородные и запятая не нужна. Но запятую можно поставить, если хотите присоединение (сказать не сразу, а вдобавок).

Comment: Извиняюсь, если это не по правилам форума, но, чтобы не создавать отдельный вопрос и чтобы все-таки разобраться, повторю предложение. **Я подумал: вероятно, приступ с Лешей случается не в первый раз(,) и, наверное, он хорошо знает, как ведет себя в таком состоянии.** Что здесь делать с запятой перед "и"? Тоже однородности нет? Oleedd, спасибо за прошлые ответы.

Comment: @Александр Здесь есть варианты. Сами предложения не очень однородные, второе похоже на вывод, а вывод, как и следствие, желательно пунктуационно отобразить. Но если не против перед обоими предложениями поставить "что", запятую не надо. Прямая связь предложений с глаголом значительно сильнее следствия и всего прочего (в примере из вопроса такого нет, там подчинительный союз не вставить). Решается так: подумал о двух вещах в один момент либо подумал об одном, а потом сделал вывод. Также следует всегда учитывать, что, чем длиннее предложения, тем неудачнее их объединение.

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю на второй вопрос (ответ на первый вопрос дан в комментарии).

*Затем гол забили мюнхенцы: атакующий смог удачно принять мяч, и тот, **задержавшись в ногах у игрока лишь на пару секунд**, влетел в сетку.*

Из правила Розенталя об общем элементе: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

3. Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними **бессоюзной связью**: *Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива* (М. Г.);

Да, может быть, но не всегда бывает. Из правил грамматики известно, что предложения в этом случае должны быть **однородными** (тогда они обозначают одновременные или последовательные события).
Но в данном случае предложения неоднородны по своей структуре, так второе предложение включает обособленный **деепричастный оборот**.

Разумеется, объединить такие предложения не представляется возможным, в том числе их нельзя связать интонационно. Поэтому запятая **ставится**, и это тот случай, который **не подходит** под общее правило.

Но попробуем упростить предложение: *Затем гол забили мюнхенцы: атакующий смог удачно принять мяч и тот влетел в сетку.*

В этом предложении бессоюзная связь будет **общим элементом**, поэтому запятая **не ставится.**

**Дополнение**

Конечно, и в упрощенном предложении запятую **можно поставить**, но из **семантических соображений** (и это уже выбор автора).

(1) Вероятно, изображение **двух ситуаций** смотрится более художественно, здесь даже тире можно поставить для большего эффекта: *Затем гол забили мюнхенцы: атакующий смог удачно принять мяч – и тот влетел в сетку.*

Другой вариант **обоснования** такой: местоимение "тот" теоретически может относиться и к футболисту, и к мячу, поэтому лучше разделить их паузой.

**Вывод**

Но в любом случае **НЕ ПРИЧИННО-СЛЕДСТВЕННЫЕ ОТНОШЕНИЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЮТ ЗДЕСЬ ВЫБОР ЗНАКА,** хотя для школьного ответа такой вариант **удобен и узнаваем** – ведь  вникать в подробности никто будет. Там послушание и готовые ответы – вот что главное, вот что ценится.

Но мы не в школе учимся, и скорее всего настоящей причиной является даже не та, о которой я говорила. Это только принятая формулировка в грамматике, да и в правилах тоже, где всегда допускаются исключения. В действительности же  **АВТОР, ОН ЖЕ ХУДОЖНИК СЛОВА, РЕШАЕТ, КАК ЕМУ ИЗОБРАЗИТЬ СОБЫТИЯ.**

**И НИКТО ЕМУ НЕ УКАЗ**, читайте Пушкина (очищает душу, очень рекомендую):

Зачем крутится ветр в овраге,

Подъемлет лист и пыль несет,

Когда корабль в недвижной влаге

Его дыханья жадно ждет?

Зачем от гор и мимо башен

Летит орел, тяжел и страшен,

На черный пень? Спроси его.

Зачем Арапа своего

Младая любит Дездемона,

Как месяц любит ночи мглу?

Затем, что ветру и орлу

И сердцу девы нет закона.

**Гордись: таков и ты, поэт,**

**И для тебя условий нет.**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133566/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).

Comment: Не вижу здесь следствия, как Катерина (смотрел футбол). А вы? Удачный пас ничего не гарантирует. Вижу просто последовательность действий. Почему надо запятую? Просто однородность — когда предложения независимые, а здесь одно ссылается на другое.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ, который был принят как правильный, не является верным, так как в этом правиле указано, что подлежащее второго предложения должно быть не только личным местоимением (‟тот”, кстати, не личное местоимение),  но оно также должно обозначать то же самое, что и обозначает подлежащее первого предложения; а в этом предложении слово ‟тот” относится к слову ‟мяч”, а не к подлежащему ‟атакующий”. [Ссылка на правило (пункт 1, примечание).](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133) Если подлежащее второго предложения просто является личным местоимением, то это правило не работает, что подтверждают многочисленные примеры из Нац. корпуса:

> Он сказал, что его очень тронуло твое письмо и он пишет тебе. [Самуил Маршак. Письма (1950-1964)]

> У нас есть знакомая Ариадна Борисовна, может быть, это была она и он спутал. [Б. Л. Пастернак. Письма А. С. Эфрон (1948-1955)]

> Мальчик был мобилизован в 1943 году, когда ему исполнилось семнадцать лет и он еще учился в гимназии. [Константин Симонов. Япония. 46 (1946 , 1976)]

В итоге, запятая не ставится, так как у двух сложносочинённых есть общее сочетание: **‟Затем гол забили мюнхенцы: атакующий смог удачно принять мяч и тот, задержавшись в ногах у игрока лишь на пару секунд, влетел в сетку.”**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ К ОТВЕТУ:**

Правила, при котором запятая ставится при сложносочинённой связи и причинно-следственных отношениях, несмотря на общий элемент, — просто нету. Такого правила не существует. Я даже в Нац. корпус идти не буду, а просто найду такие примеры в справочнике Розенталя:

> Вскоре после восхода набежала туча и брызнул короткий дождь (П.).
> Уже совсем рассвело и народ стал подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату (Л. Т.).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133691/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett----).

Answer (score 0):

Комментарий

Здесь я могу сказать следующее. (Если наши мнения будут совпадать, то стоит разговаривать дальше.)

1. Посмотрите на мое предложение: ***Затем гол забили мюнхенцы: атакующий смог удачно принять мяч и тот влетел в сетку.*** Вы будете ставить запятую? Они стали однородными? А ведь ничего не изменилось, только нет деепричастного оборота.

Это очень интересная проверка (назовем ее **«ловушка ума»**). Нам хочется найти причину для постановки запятой, и мы ее находим! Окружающие нас поддерживают (голосами, комментариями).  **Поймали  (все вместе!) истину**, вот она, в клеточке. А элементарная проверка, говорит, что это не так. Но ум и на это "машет рукой": не видит, не принимает в расчет.

2. В нашем мире все события определяются **причинно-следственными связями**  (по крайне мере, в нашей картине мира). Тогда однородных (независимых) событий вообще не существует!

А дело тут **в Наблюдателе** (центральная фигура в современной физике и философии). Мы можем самостоятельно **замечать или не замечать** причинно-следственные связи. Если в текущей ситуации они важны для нас, то мы признаем их и обозначаем на письме знаками. Если ими можно пренебречь, то не делаем этого. Это вполне разумный подход – иначе бы в наших текстах были преимущественно тире и двоеточия.

Такая ситуация и в нашем случае: разве кто-нибудь **сомневался** в наличие причинных отношений между двумя изображенными событиями? Нет, конечно, все их видели. Но надо ли их учитывать – ведь можно считать события  **последовательными** и поэтому однородными. Именно в этот момент и решается задача.

3. Все говорят, что запятая здесь нужна, и мне захотелось найти **настоящую причину неоднородности.** Для этого был приведен пример без деепричастного оборота. И вот если  вы не ставите там запятую, то проверка удалась. Истинная причина – в  **осложненности второго предложения** (вставным деепричастным оборотом, собственными знаками и интонацией). А все остальное – построения нашего ума: хочу так видеть – и вижу!

Comment: *..."Затем гол забили мюнхенцы: атакующий смог удачно принять мяч и тот влетел в сетку. Вы будете ставить запятую?*" — буду, ориентируясь на (согласен, притянутое тут за уши) правило Розенталя о постановке запятой из § 30.1.1 примеч. и учитывая, что "тот" здесь в функции личного местоимения. // Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры, где бы в подобном случае запятая не стояла. Я, в свою очередь, привёл вчера пример, что осложнение не является причиной неоднородности. // "И вот если вы не ставите там запятую, то проверка удалась". — разве что проверка на грамотность, как по мне.

Comment: 1. Розенталя § 30.1.1 говорит о том, что предложение считается сложным, если субъект действия  выражен различными способами, в том числе местоимением, на которое все «засмотрелись» :) Это другая тема: как отличить сложное предложение от простого (с однородными сказуемыми), но это не тема однородности и общего элемента.  2. Я, конечно, потом взгляну на разговор (просто не люблю лазить по чатам), но вы для себя обратите внимание вот на что.

Comment: Тоже бы поставил.

Comment: Просмотрите всю тему общего элемента у Розенталя и обратите внимание на структуру предложений. В основном это простые структуры, которые в устной речи легко можно связать в одну фонетическую фразу. А главное, есть ли среди них ВСТАВОЧНОЕ ОБОСОБЛЕНИЕ: ведь оно в середине предложения требует для себя особых знаков и вставочной интонации, так о какой однородности может идти речь. (Кстати, Розенталь не пользуется термином «однородность» для ССП.)  Поэтому в моем предложении не надо ставить запятую, Розенталь вам говорил про другое...

Comment: Ну, если уж oleedd поставил бы, то вопрос можно считать закрытым. Что ж, поздравляю всю КОМАНДУ с успехом (думаю, что зрители тоже аплодируют). А я не в вашей команде,  Ну да ладно, найду себе другую аудиторию , чтобы высказать свое мнение. Да, oleedd?  Мои слушатели – это пока мои молчаливые читатели, а мои лучшие друзья – грамматические справочники и учебники.  Школьный формализм  с его готовыми ответами на все мне тоже не подходит.

Comment: @Sharon Чем короче, тем лучше соединяется, это да. Но здесь проблема не только в длине, а и в том, что второе предложение ссылается на первое, а это нарушает однородность. И честно говоря, предложения соединяются интонационно до оборота (до паузы). Существенно мешал бы оборот до союза, а после — уже не очень.

Comment: @oleedd
Да, да, все это расскажите вашим благодарным слушателям, им всё понравится.  Только хорошо, если вы для слова "однородность" подберете ясное и четкое определение,  а остальные с ним согласятся. Ну чтобы "балагана" не получалось. И сформулируйте общий принцип — какой РЕАЛЬНЫЙ смысл в общем элементе? Насколько это авторский выбор?  Формализм  уходит в прошлое, начальную школу письма мы уже прошли. Главное  для писателя — наилучшим образом выразить свою мысль. Иногда удобно изобразить две ситуации, в другом случае — одну.  А вы с головой погрузились в этот формализм... Но это ваш выбор.

Comment: @Sharon вы так и не привели ни попрошенного мною примера, ни ссылок на конкретные параграфы конретных грамматических справочников. У меня возникает мысль, что вам весь ваш спич про Наблюдателя и прочее хорошо бы попытаться примерить на себя. Возможно, это *вы* попали в ловушку ума, увидели в предложении нечто, чего там нет, а не *мы* проглядели "настоящую причину неоднородности". Ещё раз: я не увидел в вашей аргументации никаких ссылок на неоднократно упоминавшиеся грамматические нормы.

Comment: @Nektoid  Scribitur ad narrandum, non ad probandum (говорю, чтобы рассказать, а не доказать). Версию про Наблюдателя я, конечно, отношу и к себе, и ко всем людям вообще. Мы так устроены, это можно видеть на простых бытовых примерах, а в любой науке тем более.  Не понравилась вам моя риторика, я это вижу, но это неплохо: даже негативные эмоции иногда приносят пользу.  Вы не готовы меня слушать,  так зачем же я буду что-то приводить и аргументировать.  И что вам до неправильного мнения одного человека, пусть себе заблуждается. Зато вы будете чувствовать себя комфортно среди мыслящих одинаково.

Comment: @Sharon Это как бы авторский выбор, но всегда есть лучшее решение (ровно 50 на 50 не будет), а его определить — надо уметь. Ведь запятая здесь не формальна, она влияет на прочтение.

Comment: Не вы ли сами говорили, что грамматика наука строгая, ну и т. п., а теперь вы отказываетесь от аргуметации, ссылаясь на латинскую сентенцию? Высокий уровень научного диспута, ничего не скажешь. // На основании чего вы решили, что я не готов вас слушать? Это похоже на попытку перевалить ответственность за нежелание аргументировать на другого человека. Не "я не аргументирую, потому что нечем", а "я не аргументирую, потому что другой не слушает". Нет, со мной такая подмена не прокатит. Я *уже* слушаю, внимательно; правда, пока ничего не услышал, кроме рассуждений без опоры.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не сердитесь, на меня, нет настроения рассказывать. Может быть, в другом лунном цикле, а?  И слушать вы тоже не готовы, эмоционально не настроены, бесполезный будет разговор.